# How we define levels in getParentNode ( tree behavior cakephp )

Tags: cakephp, tree

I am tried getParentNode and it's work perfectly but it dosent work correctly when I tried to define the parent's level like  $data = $this->Category->getParentNode(44,null,2); it change nothing !

I need your helps please !